# c++ inline function example

Tags: c++, inline

I follow this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inline_functions.htm:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline int Max(int x, int y)
{
   return (x > y)? x : y;
}

// Main function for the program
int main( )
{

   cout << "Max (20,10): " << Max(20,10) << endl;
   cout << "Max (0,200): " << Max(0,200) << endl;
   cout << "Max (100,1010): " << Max(100,1010) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

and tried removing the inline and still gives same results... so what does inline actually affect this?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it give you the same results?! `inline` is about controlling ODR, not changing the meaning of numbers...

Comment: Oh dear. `using namespace std;` is a terrible habit. Avoid it!  For the actual question, are you familiar with normal usage of header files and source files?

Comment: it's just a copy-paste from the site...

Answer (score 1):

`inline` has nothing whatsoever to do with the *behavior* of the function. The only thing it is *required* to do is alter the behavior of the linker, specifically to cause the linker to allow the same symbol to be defined in multiple translation units. `inline` never affects a program's observed behavior<sup>1</sup>, only whether or not it might link successfully.

In the past it was also used as a hint to the compiler that the function should be inlined whenever used, but this is not required by the C++ specification and modern compilers are very good at deciding whether to inline without input from the programmer.

In the code you have posted, `inline` will not have any observable effect.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless you define a function multiple times *differently* in different translation units and declare them all `inline` -- but I think this invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the difference between your code's operation using `assembly` output.

To view this using `g++` as a compiler, type:

```
g++ -S mySource.cpp -o assemblyWithInline
```

then remove your `inline` and try, for example,

```
g++ -S myNewSource.cpp -o assemblyWithoutInline
diff assemblyWithInline assemblyWithoutInline
```

This will display the difference between your two sets of code (as understood by your compiler, `g++`)

This may be the same, if your compiler optimises your code to automatically `inline` it.

The output in all cases will be the same, since your logic is not altered by the presence of an `inline` hint.

Answer (score 0):

Inline is Just a hint for the compiler. It can provide somę measurable speed up of code making calls to Inline functions.

Modern compilers seam to be far more clever these days so they know in 99% situations where Inline would help and where code would suffer from such inline.

Basicly inlined function code is pasted at every (suitable) call instruction, reducing overhead of pushing and popping its arguments.

Comment: -1 It is not *just* a hint for the compiler; it affects link-time behavior. If you define (as opposed to declare) a function in a header file that is included into multiple translation units, `inline` is *required* on that function or it will fail to link. The only behavior `inline` is guaranteed to have is the suppression of the One Definition Rule (ODR).